# How do I remove all symbols from the beginning and end of a string, if any?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Keep only the alphabet and numbers.

`--I have a dog!!!` should result in `I have a dog`

`I have a dog.` should result in `I have a dog`

Comment: Sorry for flame, but seeing so many people fighting to answer such a simple question... it is just hilarious :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing with this regex:

```
/^[^a-z\d]*|[^a-z\d]*$/gi
```

Comment: Why did you add this edit? We've just discussed with you that `\w` matches underscore, and OP doesn't want this.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "--I have a dog!!!"
s.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z\d]*(.*?)([^a-zA-Z\d])*$/, "$1")
```

Please note, that this will do *exactly* what you asked for. It will remove non-alphanumeric characters *only* from the beginning and from the end of the string. All non-alpha and non-digits in the middle of the string won't be removed.

Comment: @TimPietzcker What do yo mean no need? It must be non-greedy to work, of course.

Comment: @TimPietzcker And yeah, I fixed the case of `z`, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular expressions and replace

```
'--I have a dog!!!'.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]*/g,''); // "I have a dog"
```

That will remove from every location of string any other characters than numbers, letters and spaces.

If you want explicitly remove from beginning and end only, then you will need something like this:

```
'--I have !!! a dog!!!'.replace(/^[^a-zA-Z 0-9]*|[^a-zA-Z 0-9]*$/g,''); // "I have !!! a dog"
```

Learn more regex at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html), there are JavaScript examples too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x = '--I have a dog!!!';
x = x.replace(/[^0-9A-Za-z\s]/g, '');

// results in "I have a dog"
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Not at all. Did you try it. Did you see the `\s` there. BTW, i test using chrome console before posting anything :-)

Comment: OK, I seem not to be in top form this morning. Sorry. But still this regex doesn't fulfill the requirement "remove from the start/end of the string".

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Ahh, you're right. Cannot look into beginning and end without using `|`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Regex to solve this:

```
var s = '--I have a dog!!!';
s = s.replace(/^[^a-z\d]*|[^a-z\d]*$/gi, '');
```

Comment: Afaic it soesn't include `!` but it definitely includes `_`.

Comment: @elclanrs I have no idea why this happens. I've tried `"hi!".match(/\w*/)` in my browser, and sure enough it matched `"hi"`.

Comment: @elclanrs Also, I have no reason to think that mozilla dev network is lying. And it says “Matches any alphanumeric character including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_].” https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @kirelagin: Mmmm, you're right, I've no idea then. I imagined it would be some JS thing where `\w` matches `!` as well. It is strange. Maybe somebody could enlighten us...

Comment: Yes: Your regex matches the empty string before `H`.

Comment: @elclanrs the regx you've posted at jsbin just doesn't do anything at the end of the string. That's expected.

Comment: @kirelagin: I just copy/pasted this code straight into JSBin. My point was to prove that this answer doesn't do what OP had in mind.

Comment: @elclanrs Well, yeah, this code is clearly broken, but this has nothing to do with behaviour of `\w`.